Is there a class of functions for which the Newton's method applied for a Nash Equilibrium problem yields sequences with same order of convergence?
Suppose you have the Nash Equilibrium problem of finding $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$ such that
$x_1^* \in argmin_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1}}\{f_1(x,x_2^*)\}$
$x_2^* \in argmin_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2}}\{f_1(x_1^*,x)\}$
The necessary first order optimality condition is $\nabla_{i}f_i(x_1^*,x^*_2)= 0$ for $i=1,2$. Suppose we make a Newton method for this optimality condition constructing the sequence
$x^k - x^{k-1} = -H^{-1}(x^k)(\nabla_1f_1(x^k), \nabla_2 f_2(x^k))^T$,
the standard Newton iteration for the Nash Equilibrium.
I want to know... Is there a class of functions where it is certain that the components $x_i^k$ converge to $x_i^*$ on the same rate? Because they could converge in different rates, right?
For instance, if both $f_i$ are equal the same $f$, can one say that the convergence rate componentwise is the same? Or any other class of functions, really. Are there any results on that line?
